# QUERY - Alguém pode me ajudar a montar essa query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho essas 3 tabelas abaixo: "users", "friends" e "posts".

Eu quero pegar todos os meus amigos que estão na tabela de friends e exibir os posts deles, pegando o nome de cada um e sua imagem(que estão na tabela de users).

Imaginem um feed de notícias, onde eu tenho que mostrar as postagens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria tentar fazer so com JOINS, sem usar subselect(que foi a forma que eu encontrei de fazer)

Obrigado!

Comment: Isso é fácil de fazer, mas o que você já tentou?

Comment: SELECT p.descr,p.dt_hr,
(SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = f.id_friend) AS name
FROM friends f
JOIN users u ON u.id = f.id_user
JOIN posts p ON p.id_user = f.id_friend
WHERE u.id = 1
ORDER BY p.dt_hr DESC

Comment: A que eu montei foi essa acima, mas eu preciso retornar dois campos desse subselect, e ele so retorna 1. No caso, eu preciso do nome e da imagem...

Comment: e qual a dificuldade em fazer mais um join com ele?

Comment: não estou conseguindo, poderia ajudar?

Comment: veja  se era isso que você queria.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, é pq eu ja fazia um join na users, não acharia que precisava fazer mais um, sacou? Mas valeu cara. Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça;

```
 SELECT p.descr,p.dt_hr , u1.name, u1.img
    FROM friends f 
    JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = f.id_user 
    JOIN posts p 
    ON p.id_user = f.id_friend 
    join users u1 
    on u1.id = f.id_friend
    WHERE u.id = 1 
    ORDER BY p.dt_hr DESC
```